# Accessing samba shares?

Tags: networking, server, mount, samba, cron

I'm trying to automate a task with **Crontab** and here's the output:
" **gio: smb://server_name/shares: volume doesn’t implement mount** "

When I **login** to ubuntu-server directly (in the main machine) or via ssh (info: I have only one user and the root :)" and I type (same command as in the script!).

$ **echo -e "USER\nDOMAIN\nPASS\n" | gio mount smb://server_name/shares**

it works well.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running crontab from the root account. `gio` is designed to run from a *user* account rather than root, so you'll need to pass a username in crontab like this:

```
0 * * * * su {username} -c {command}
```

Be sure to replace `{username}` with the user account's name, and `{command}` with what you want the job to do.